# create single key shortcut for multiple keystrokes

Tags: javascript

I want to add an eventlistener to my existing code which reacts to a single key combination (alt+1) and gives me multiple keys (1,2,1 for example) as an output, ideally with a delay of 1ms inbetween the single outputs. How, and where to start?

I wrote an eventlistener in the past, which activates a snippet of code with a delay, but don't know how to get it to work for multiple keycodes...

```
function test(){
setTimeout(function(){ example(); }, 1);
}

 document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
 if (e.keyCode == 113) {
 console.log("f2 success");
 test(); 
 }             
}, false);
```

Comment: what do you mean by .`multiple keycodes...`

IS it like the combination of ctrl +1 or `1+1+3`

Comment: You can wait for till user stops typing and at the end you have a complete value like `113`

Comment: I mean that by pressing alt+1 you'll get the output of 1, 1, 1 (1ms delay in between each one)

Comment: setTimeout already has +/-4ms delay by default.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  console.log( 'Button «' + e.keyCode + '» was pressed' );
  
  if( e.altKey && ( e.keyCode == 49 || e.keyCode == 97 )  ){ // [ALT + 1]
    document.dispatchEvent( new KeyboardEvent( "keydown", { bubbles: true, keyCode: 49 }) ); // [1]
    document.dispatchEvent( new KeyboardEvent( "keydown", { bubbles: true, keyCode: 49 }) ); // [1]
    document.dispatchEvent( new KeyboardEvent( "keydown", { bubbles: true, keyCode: 51 }) ); // [3]
  }

});
```